# XSLT to remove an Element's Value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to remove a value from an element, but preserve the element itself in the output XML as an empty element.

My input file:

```
<a>
    <b>TEXT1
        <c>123</c>
        <d>qwe</d>
        <e>rty</e>
    </b>
    <b>TEXT2
    <c>345</c>
    <d>iop</d>
    <e>jkl</e>
    </b>
</a>
```

The output file should retain element c, but the numbers in the element should be gone.

```
<a>
<b>TEXT1
    <c></c>
    <d>qwe</d>
    <e>rty</e>
</b>
<b>TEXT2
    <c></c>
    <d>iop</d>
    <e>jkl</e>
</b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <c/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<a>
   <b>TEXT1
    <c/>
      <d>qwe</d>
      <e>rty</e>
   </b>
   <b>TEXT2
    <c/>
      <d>iop</d>
      <e>jkl</e>
   </b>
</a>
```

Note: `<c/>` and `<c></c>` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

**Even simpler/shorter**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="c/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: And of course the "|@*" is redundant if the source document contains no attributes.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Yes. Keeping this redundancy allows the same code to process correctly not only the specific provided document, but a class of documents, some of which would have attributes.