# XSLT to remove an Element's value based on attribute value using namespaced xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

using [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786455/remove-xml-node-based-on-attribute-value-with-xslt) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879831/xslt-to-remove-an-elements-value) I am able to remove an Element's value based on attribute value using XSLT on non-namespaced XML
But my input looks like this

```
<tns:message xmlns:tns="http://www.co.com/schemas/sys">
   <Body xmlns="http://co.com/message">
      <Record xmlns="http://schemas.co.com/Record/1.0">
         <Book Class="NOVEL">Jungle Book</Book>
         <Book Class="AUTOBIOGRAPHY">The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</Book>
      </Record>
   </Body>
</tns:message>
```

I have tried to use XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msg="http://co.com/message"
xmlns:rec="http://schemas.co.com/Record/1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="msg:Body/rec:Record/Book[@Class = 'NOVEL']/text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But no luck.
When I have added namespace prefixes into input then it has worked.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default namespaces (without a prefix) are inherited. That means that the `Book` elements in your input are in the same namespace as their parent `Record` - and you need to change this:

```
<xsl:template match="msg:Body/rec:Record/Book[@Class = 'NOVEL']/text()" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="msg:Body/rec:Record/rec:Book[@Class = 'NOVEL']/text()" />
```